# Linux shell command isn't executed as expected

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I'm need to launch headless LibreOffice on a web server which processes Calc spreadsheet from template. I tried to do this straight in Python with the command below.

```
# Doesn't work as expected, no socket connection, "--accept ..." is ignored.
subprocess.Popen(['libreoffice', '--calc','--headless', 
'--accept="socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;"','&'], shell=True)
```

However, when I launch Shell script from Python, everything is OK.

```
subprocess.call('/var/www/scripts/service_report_ods_prepare.sh', shell=True)
```

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

app="soffice"

app_pid=`ps -ef | grep "$app" | awk '{print $2}'`

if `ps -p $app_pid > /dev/null`; then
    echo "An instance of LibreOffice is running, pid = "$app_pid
    echo "Not starting another instance."
else
    libreoffice --headless --accept="socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;"& > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

What is wrong with my Python code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `shell=True` here? (Okay, the `&` is the obvious reason, but you don't _need_ a `&` to put something in the background with `subprocess.Popen`; it _never_ does an implicit `wait()`, so everything is already implicitly in the background by default and only changes to be in the foreground when you use `subprocess.call()` instead, or call `wait()`, `communicate()`, etc)

Comment: `&` is not an argument; it's a *terminator* for a shell command.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

Do *one* of the following:

1. Drop the `shell=True` (use `shell=False`)
2. Put the entire command line into a single string and use it instead of the array: `subprocess.Popen('libreoffice --calc ...', shell=True)`. Make sure to escape the command properly.
3. Put the entire command line into the first and *the only element* of the `args`. Make sure to escape the command properly.
4. Modify the first argument so that it accepts the positional arguments, e.g.: `'libreoffice "$@"'`, where `"$@"` expands to quoted list of positional arguments.

---

[The docs for `subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) state:

> On POSIX with `shell=True`, the shell defaults to `/bin/sh`. If `args` is a string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell. This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. **If `args` is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself**. That is to say, Popen does the equivalent of:
>
> Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])

Therefore, the following code:

```py
subprocess.Popen(['libreoffice', '--calc','--headless',
'--accept="socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;"','&'], shell=True)
```

is equivalent to the following shell command on POSIX:

```
/bin/sh -c libreoffice --calc --headless --accept="socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;" &
```

which actually runs `libreoffice` **script** and passes the rest of the arguments (`--calc`, `--headless` etc.) to this "script" as `$0` (`--calc`), `$1` (`--headless`) etc. But the positional arguments are never used in the script, so the code actually runs just `libreoffice` command.

Refer to the man page for `sh` (`man sh`):

> -c        If  the -c option is present, then commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.  If there are arguments after the command_string, the first argument is assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to the positional parameters.  The assignment to $0 sets the name of the shell, which is used in warning and error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks everyone for help!
This did the trick.

```
subprocess.Popen(['libreoffice', '--calc', '--headless', 
    '--norestore', '--nofirststartwizard', '--nologo', 
    '--accept="socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;"'], shell=False)
```